# "The selected files was not found" on an InfoPath form in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

When using a file attachment control on a InfoPath form as part of a SharePoint workflow I get the error "The selected files was not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this online somewhere but can't find it again to link. You need to modify the following file:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\WrkTaskIP.aspx

Add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">aspnetForm.encoding = "multipart/form-data";</script>
```

into the file just before the first table opening tag. iisreset and then the attachment control of the form should work when hosted inside a workflow.